# python for loops

Tags: python, loops

Im trying to use this http://code.google.com/p/pywhois/
along with the socket.gethostbyaddr .

```
import socket
import pywhois

revip = socket.gethostbyaddr('50.57.48.133')
whois = pywhois.whois(revip[0])
for i in whois.emails:
 print
```

Gives me three lines of nothing. Im trying to print out the emails from the whois query. The data stored inside whois.emails is

```
['josh.odom@rackspace.com', 'josh.odom@rackspace.com', 'support@clickandname.com']
```

Whats going wrong here?

Comment: "too localized"? How is iterating over a loop too localized?

Comment: No one else will ever quit the tutorial quite that soon again.

Comment: In general you should not call variables `i` unless it is a numeric index; it's misleading, sort of like defining a variable `name = 5`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the code working, you need to add i after print:

```
for i in whois.emails:
  print i # you may see print(i) because in Python 3 print is a function.
          # and it does not matter in Python < 3
```

To get this format

> ['josh.odom@rackspace.com', 'josh.odom@rackspace.com', 'support@clickandname.com']

you call print on the entire list (no looping):

```
print whois.emails
```

Comment: What I'm trying todo is add in a function to fail2ban that will query a whois server and get the contact information to include in a email that is sent to the administrator when a ip is banned for violating one of the rules. Im having a hard time doing this as I have only been python prgramming for less than a hour.

Answer (score 2):

```
print i
```

That should solve your problem.

Comment: You an also make it `print (i)` for forward compatibility. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should do `print i` instead of just `print`.